# Android fragments: savedInstanceState is always null despite onSaveInstanceState is called

Tags: java, android

The fragment method **onCreateView** is always called with **savedInstanceState** null value.

What I do is:

1. FragmentA is created inside an activity.
2. FragmentB is created and FragmentA is replaced like this:

   `FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentA.getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentB);
           ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
           ft.addToBackStack(null);
           ft.commit();`
3. The method `onSaveInstanceState` for fragmentA is called. Inside the overwritten method the `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)` is written at the top.
4. I press back button from Android UI to pop FragmentB and show again fragmentA.
5. Method `onCreateView` for FragmentA is called again, but savedInstanceState is null.

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance.